# How can I obtain all of the street names under a polygon in Overpass?

Tags: overpass-api

I am new to overpass (after only discovering it last night). I have a polygon I drew on QGIS and I plan to obtain its coordinates (long, lat). I'd then like to use these coordinates in overpass to obtain all of the road names in that area. I found a query online that obtains all road names in a city:

```
[out:csv ("name")][timeout:2500];
{{geocodeArea:Roma}}->.searchArea;
(
  way["highway"]["name"](area.searchArea);
);
for (t["name"])
{
  make street name=_.val;
  out;
}
```

How can I adjust the following query so that I can specify a polygon function instead of city/area name?. I'm mindful of the syntax:

```
  (poly:"latitude_1 longitude_1 latitude_2 longitude_2 latitude_3 longitude_3 …");
```

I'm just not sure where it would go in the query. I tried a few times but I was receiving errors or just blank results. Hopefully if I see an example I should be able to carry out my task effectively.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research I found the answer. This would give me a list of road names:

```
[out:csv ("name")][timeout:2500];

way["highway"]["name"]
    (poly:"51.5566 0.0763 51.5734 0.0724 51.5203 0.0293");
out tags;
```

And this would give me a map view:

```
way["highway"]["name"]
    (poly:"51.5566 0.0763 51.5734 0.0724 51.5203 0.0293");
out geom;
```